# Glassfish 4 domain dies without log entry

Tags: glassfish

I have a Glassfish 4 server with 4 domains running.

A minimum of once a day, some domin just dies without a single entry in the log files. I restart it with asadmin start-domain domainxxx and it works fine again.

All domains are running one single app, while one domain is also running a few additional apps.

The system did run without problem on Glassfish 3.

Since I don't know whats happening - no logs, nothing - I don't know where to start.

Any suggestions there to start looking?

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing the same problem on Glassfish 3

Comment: Yes, the problem was low memory, and the os killed one of the Glassfish processes.